# Disable microphone loopback into headset

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Using an USB headset (Logitech G Pro X) with integrated sound card, I get an annoying loopback from the microphone into the headset, and I can't figure out how to disable it without muting the microphone completely.

So far, what I have checked :

- In Volume Control (pavucontrol):

  - the microphone input volume cursor won't affect the volume of the loopback, only the one other people hear. But if I click on the "mute" button, the loopback stops too.
  - same behavior with the headset output volume cursor.
- in alsamixer, there is no "loopback" cursor mentionned on my headset's sound card
- as I had made a few tests before, I made sure PulseAudio loopback module isn't loaded:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

- result of `pacmd list-cards` : https://pastebin.com/u807SsF8

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

### Edit with solution:

As expained by Alejandro, this is a feature called **sidetone**. To edit its volume under Linux, I used this [HeadsetControl tool](https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl).

#### Older versions of HeadsetControl

On older versions of HeadsetControl, the tool was only designed to work with the Logitech G Pro. To work with a Logitech G Pro X, I had (at the time) to change the following line of code in `src/devices/logitech_gpro.c` and recompile the tool:

```c
// from:
static const uint16_t PRODUCT_ID = 0x0aa7; // PRO X: 0x0aaa
// to:
static const uint16_t PRODUCT_ID = 0x0aaa; // PRO X: 0x0aaa
```

Once compiled, I was able to change the change the sidetone's volume using a value between 0 and 128:

```bash
sudo headsetcontrol -s 16
```

Comment: G Pro X is supported by HeadsetControl now, so no need to compile the program yourself. https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl/blob/1194d6003599b7874d8f576554fa3b698090f5a2/src/devices/logitech_gpro.c#L13-L15

Comment: Thanks. I edited the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Logitech G Pro X has it's own **loopback** feature (also called **monitor** or **sidetone**). Ubuntu's sound volume settings won't affect the volume of the sidetone; however, whenever the mic is muted, the sidetone is disabled too.

Try to connect the headset to a Windows computer and use [Logitech G HUB](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025298133) to adjust or disable the loopback/monitor/sidetone feature.

Another option would be to try to use [this tool](https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl) in Ubuntu to control the sidetone feature of your headset.

Please confirm which option works for you, if any.

Comment: Note that, with the adequate settings, the **sidetone** can be a very useful feature for a headset. It makes it easier to speak at the adequate volume, without shouting, during online gameplay or meetings.

Comment: Wow thank you. As I don't have any Windows around, I'll try the HeadsetControl tool you mentioned. I do find this sidetone useful, but it is too loud and if I can't tweak its volume I will have to disable it. I'll get back to you after using the tool.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you again

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful. Nice edit on your side explaining the full solution. Thank you very much too.